# git work on small branch that has dependency on unmerged branch

Tags: git

This is a problem I've encountered a few times and am curious what the right course of action is. I'm sure it's been asked before but I can't find the right language for the title.

I have a large feature branch checked out, that is still being reviewed, we'll call it `branch A`

I'm working on a smaller feature on `branch B`, but it's actually dependent on code that's in `branch A`

If I just merge `branch A` into `branch B`, I'll eventually have tons of conflicts when I go to merge `branch B` into master, because it will also have all of the changes from `branch A`

Assuming I can't just merge `branch A` into master before pulling it and then working on `branch B`, what's one to do in this situation?

Comment: `git rerere` is designed for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I try to isolate the code I need from `branch A` in a **single commit** *(I use interactive rebase `git rebase -i` to isolate this code if it is not yet in a separate commit)* and then I `cherry-pick` **this commit** to `branch B`